# Is there a specific symbol for denoting a linear subspace like $\subseteq$ for denoting a subset?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I was under the impression that this was a proper notation, but I was just corrected on this but did not get a proper explanation of what it should be. I get that it is definitely not the same, but what is the right symbol then?

So I am specifically asking for a linear subspace. Or does this not make any difference?

Comment: Not really. As you said, the set-theoretic inclusion is one to express ''subspace''.

Comment: There is no symbol really. You just say it with words or it follows from the context. Normally you "let $U,V$ be linear spaces such that $U\subseteq V$".

Comment: Some people use $G \le H$ to denote that $G$ is a subgroup of $H$; that notation could be adapted here but I've never seen it. In practice I think "let $U \subseteq V$" be a subspace" is fine.

Comment: I wish there were a standard.  I use the symbol « which Mathematica calls "LeftGuillemet".  It converts to Latex  $\langle\langle$.  Since I am the only person foolish enough to read my notes, it doesn't matter if others accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Some authors denote that as $\leq$. The inclusion $\subseteq$ of set $X$ form a partial order of the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ of a set $X$ and if $X$ is vector space then it's subspaces form the suborder as a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$. In order theory, there are many orders that use different symbols $\leq,\ \subseteq,\ \lesssim,\ \preceq,\ \unlhd$, etc.

Usually the $\subset$ symbol is used for sets. However, any symbol can be used as long as it is predefined or can be distinguished from the context. There are a myriad of orders, so there is no need to create other symbols for them.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed a linear subspace is a subset of a given linear space for which the linearity properties are preserved but there is not a specific symbol for that.

In a compact form we could use $$U=\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}\subseteq V$$ beeing $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\} \subseteq V$ a basis for $U$ or more in general any subset of the linear space $V$ depending on the context we are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for the same question and the first thing I saw was the [Subspace Army](https://supersmashbros.fandom.com/wiki/Subspace_Army) emblem from Super Smash Bros. Brawl. So here is my entry for the "subspace" symbol:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\subspace}{%
\ 
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw[] (0,0) circle (0.75ex);
\draw[] (0,0) -- (0.75ex,0);%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\;
}

\newcommand{\superspace}{%
\ 
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw[] (0,0) circle (0.75ex);
\draw[] (0,0) -- (-0.75ex,0);%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\;
}

\begin{document}
\ \\
$A$ is a subspace of the vector space $B$: $A \subspace B$\\
$B$ is a superspace of the vector space $A$:  $B \superspace A$
\end{document}
```

[Complied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgiM9.png)

Comment: This is fun, but I would find it confusing and would wonder why the writer didn't just use something like $\subseteq$ or $\preceq$ as was suggested in the other reply.